# How to get firebase messages when new child/node/listener is added to firebase connection?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

When I use this code for the first time, I have got the data that from the firebase database connections so there is not issue in it but when a new/last child to my firebase connection I didn't get any hit from the firebase.

func fireBaseSubscription() {

```
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ISUSERLOGGEDIN") == true{

        let fireBaseNode = (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "firebase_node") as? [String])!
        let ref = Database.database().reference()

        for i in fireBaseNode {
            // one_to_one_chat Listner


             ref.child(i).child("one_to_one_chat").queryLimited(toLast: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

             let postOnetoOneChatDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
             self.fireBaseOnetoOneChatListner(postOnetoOneChatDict: postOnetoOneChatDict!)

             print(snapshot)
             print(postOnetoOneChatDict as Any)
             }, withCancel: { (Error) in
             print(Error)
             })

             // users listner
             ref.child(i).child("users").queryLimited(toLast: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
             let postUserDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
             self.fireBaseUsersListner(postUserDict: postUserDict!)
             print(snapshot)
             print(postUserDict as Any)
             }, withCancel: { (Error) in
             print(Error)
             })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are observing a single event by `.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded` which will be fired only once.

Change it to `.observe(.childAdded` and it will be called every time whenever a child will be added.